# Inheritence in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance

```
class Users
{
    function inWork($uid) 
    {
        $q = 'SELECT in_work FROM user_activity WHERE user_id=? LIMIT 1';

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($q);
        $params = array($uid);
        $count = $stmt->execute($params);

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row['in_work'] == 0){
            $status = 'Not Working';
        } elseif($row['in_work'] == 1){
            $status = 'Working';
        }

        return $status;
    }

}
```

And

```
class Call_log extends Users
{
    function getUserCalls($uid)
    {
        print $this->inWork($uid);
    }
}
```

And

```
$call_log = new Call_log;
print $call_log->inWork(n);
```

from client code, works and behaves correctly i.e displays 'Working' or 'Not Working' accordingly based on an integer value from the database.

A call to the same method from within `Call_log` and it doesn't work correctly or I get unexpected results.

The method outputs 'Not Working' only?

My Call_log class is inheriting all methods from Users and so calling `inWork($uid)` from within `getUserCalls($uid)` shouldn't be a problem? Or at least that's what I thought.

Background:

```
SELECT in_work FROM user_activity WHERE user_id=32 LIMIT 1;
+---------+
| in_work |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+

SELECT in_work FROM user_activity WHERE user_id=2 LIMIT 1;
+---------+
| in_work |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
```

Edit: The long version:

```
function getUserCalls($uid){

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("CALL select_calls_by_extn(?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 5);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(!$rows){
        throw new Exception('We couldn\'t find any records for that name.');
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row){

        if($row['in_work'] == 0){
            $status = 'Not Working';
        } elseif($row['in_work'] == 1){
            $status = 'Working';
        }   

        //$status = $this->inWork($uid);


        print '<tr><td>'.$row['ext_num'].'</td><td>'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$status.'</td><td>'.$row['avg_in'].'</td><td>'.$row['avg_out'].'</td><td>'.$row['calls_in'].'</td><td>'.$row['calls_out']."</td></tr>\n";
    }
}
```

I was hoping the 'commented-out' $status variable would take on a value using inheritence thus cutting down on code duplication.

Comment: `$call_log->getUserCalls($uid);` is what is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right concept. Calling `inWork` from within `getUserCalls` is perfectly valid. To ensure that your queries/stored functions aren't the issue, I'd recommend hard coding two different values and then executing methods to test if you get the correct results.

```
class Users
{
    function inWork($uid) 
    {
        // instead of getting data from the database, let's force the data 
        // to look as if the database has provided us the data. 
        // If user id 32 is passed, flag staticData to 1
        $staticData = ($uid === 32) ? 1 : 0;
        $row = array('in_work'=>$staticData);

        if($row['in_work'] == 0){
            $status = 'Not Working';
        } elseif($row['in_work'] == 1){
            $status = 'Working';
        }

        return $status;
    }
}


class CallLog extends Users
{
    function getUserCalls($uid)
    {
        echo $this->inWork($uid);
    }
}


$callLog = new CallLog();
print $callLog->inWork(2); // Should print Not Working
print $callLog->getUserCalls(2); // Should print Not working

print $callLog->inWork(32); // Should print Working
print $callLog->getUserCalls(32); // Should print working
```

Debug your application by doing a `var_dump` or `print_r` on `$rows` with the two different statements you have used:

1. `select .... from ....`, and
2. `CALL select_calls_by_extn`

You should get identical results and the results of var_dump will allow you to see what is happening with variables and if results of SQL is the actual issue.

From what I read, your theory of inheritance is alright.

Comment: That's a mystery that remains unsolved and that's with all checks as above.